# How to structure title,images and button with css,html for online shop

Tags: php, html, css

I'm still learning to program and I have some issues with my layout.
I'm developing an online shop for clothes and accessories.
I want when the user opens a page with all items being looks like this:
[image]

The items have a very good structure.
Titles, images, and descriptions are looks very good.

Here is my layout:[image]

My layout does not look very good. Titles, images, and descriptions are not in the same line.
I'm thinking that you understand what i want..
Here is my code:

```
<?php foreach($posts as $post) : ?>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4" >
                <!-- <div class="gallery"> -->
            <a href="<?php echo site_url('/posts/'.$post['slug']); ?>"><h4><?php echo word_limiter($post['title'],4); ?></h4></a>
            <?php if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) :?>
            <small class="post-date">Posted on: <?php echo $post['created_at']; ?> in <strong><?php echo $post['name']; ?></strong></small>
            <?php endif ?>

            <div class="zoom-in">
            <img class="post-thumb" width="500" height="300" src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>assets/images/posts/<?php echo $post['post_image']; ?>">
            </div>
            <!-- <?php echo word_limiter($post['body'],5); ?> -->
            <b></b><br>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger addcart" productid="<?php echo $post['id'] ?>" value="Добави в количката">
            <br><a style="color: black;"class="btn btn-link" href="<?php echo site_url('/posts/'.$post['slug']); ?>">Виж повече</a>
            </div>

            <?php endforeach; } ?>
```

Please help me how to fix this issue.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well, if it looks like a table, why not use one? Nowadays there are even [more options](https://cssgridgarden.com/), but a table is perhaps easier to use and pretty stable in display, even for older browsers.

Comment: And back in the days, I also found this reference useful: http://cssdesignpatterns.com/ - it has various examples on how to to the styling on elements.